# How to display tooltips with various data in MS charts

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, datagridview, candlestick-chart

I am developing a candle chart in C #.

I've been working on creating candle charts using data from the current datagridview.

[image]

Additionally, when I place the cursor over the candle point of the chart, I want to show the information (open, close, high, low) of the datagridview. (See image)

Currently developed source.

```
    DataTable table_ChartData = new DataTable();
    table_ChartData.Columns.Add("Id");
    table_ChartData.Columns.Add("Open");
    table_ChartData.Columns.Add("Close");
    table_ChartData.Columns.Add("High");
    table_ChartData.Columns.Add("Low");
    table_ChartData.Columns.Add("Day");
    dataGridView1.DataSource = table_ChartData;  

    chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 1;
    chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 1;
    chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Maximum = max;
    chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Minimum = min;

    chart1.Series["Daily"].XValueMember = "Day";
    chart1.Series["Daily"].YValueMembers = "High,Low,Open,Close";
    chart1.Series["Daily"].XValueType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.Date;

    chart1.Series["Daily"].CustomProperties = "PriceDownColor=Blue,PriceUpColor=Red";
    chart1.Series["Daily"]["OpenCloseStyle"] = "Triangle";
    chart1.Series["Daily"]["ShowOpenClose"] = "Both";

    chart1.DataSource = table_ChartData;
    chart1.DataBind();

    private void chart1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        Point mousePoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.SetCursorPixelPosition(mousePoint, true);
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.SetCursorPixelPosition(mousePoint, true);`

        var pos = e.Location;
        if (prevPosition.HasValue && pos == prevPosition.Value)
            return;
        tooltip.RemoveAll();
        prevPosition = pos;
        var results = chart1.HitTest(pos.X, pos.Y, false, ChartElementType.DataPoint); // set ChartElementType.PlottingArea for full area, not only DataPoints
        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            if (result.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.DataPoint) // set ChartElementType.PlottingArea for full area, not only DataPoints
            {
                var yVal = result.ChartArea.AxisY.PixelPositionToValue(pos.Y);
                tooltip.Show(((int)yVal).ToString(), chart1, pos.X, pos.Y - 15);
            }
        }

    }
```

Thank you for your help. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating `ToolTips` in the `MouseMove`; this is one way but the easiest approach is to let the Chart do the work by setting the `DataPoint.Tooltip` property right when you create the `DataPoints`..:

```
DataPoint dp = new DataPoint (..);
dp.ToolTip = "x=" + dp.XValue + "\n high=" + dp.YValues[0]+ "\n low=" + dp.YValues[1] + ..;
yourSeries.Points.Add(dp);
```

---

.. or, if the Points are `DataBound` either add `ToolTips` right after you bind or, maybe include them in the binding itself.

Note that only some of the [various data binding methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd456766%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) will let you bind 'extended chart properties' like tooltips. `Points.DataBind` is mentioned explicitly. This means that you need a prepared field for the tooltips in your datasource as I know of no way to write a concatenating expression in the `otherField` string..

If you have your data in a `DataTable` with the fields below you can use syntax like this for the binding:

```
var enumerableTable = (dt as System.ComponentModel.IListSource).GetList();
yourSeries.Points.DataBind(enumerableTable, "x-col", 
                          "highField, lowField..", "Tooltip=tooltipField");
```

---

If you want to do it in the `MouseMove` you can easily get a reference to the `DataPoint` you are over, if any, and work with all its values like above..:

```
DataPoint dp = null;
if (results.PointIndex >= 0 && results.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.DataPoint)
{
    dp = results.Series.Points[hitt.PointIndex];
    string tText = "x=" + dp.XValue + "\n high=" + 
                   dp.YValues[0]+ "\n low=" + dp.YValues[1] + ..;
..
}
```

Note that the [HitTest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.hittest(v=vs.110).aspx) result is one object with several properties. No need to loop over it!

Comment: TaW Thank you very much. it was helpful.